# Assigning Due Date of Task Created In Workflow From Initiation Parameters

Tags: 2010, tasks

I am attempting to create a Workflow that asks the user for a due date, then assigns a task with that due date. I cannot get it to assign the date I have asked for in the Initiation Form Parameters. Is there a way to so this?

I have tried a secondary Workflow that looks in the library that the primary work flow is running in to no avail... It is difficult since the primary library is a documents library.

Is there an easy way to do this?

This is in SharePoint 2010 with Designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a due date column - it could be hidden, but make it visible on an input form.

Collect the value in designer and set your task due date to that value.

Comment: Use a due date column where? In the document library?

Comment: Yeah, you can create an additional column to store due dates (or any other metadata). You can do this with a document library - they are nearly identical to lists.